# Remove only certain squares from grid in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-intersects

So I have this grid (I create this from oriented enveloping the brown polygons and then buffering)

[image]

```
create temp table test_squares as select test_fishnet.poly from test_fishnet, polys where st_intersects(polys.poly::geometry, st_setsrid(test_fishnet.poly, 102008));
```

I then remove the squares that aren't touching the brown polygons (using the above code) to give me this:

[image]

However, I really only want to remove these squares (in yellow) and keep everything else:

[image]

The other ones in the middle, although they don't intersect the polygons, they do lie sandwiched in between ones that do. How might I keep all the purple squares?

EDIT: more info on how I make this grid:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_CreateFishnet(
    nrow integer, ncol integer,
    xsize float8, ysize float8,
    x0 float8 DEFAULT 0, y0 float8 DEFAULT 0,
    OUT "row" integer, OUT col integer,
    OUT geom geometry)
RETURNS SETOF record AS
$$
SELECT i + 1 AS row, j + 1 AS col, ST_Translate(cell, j * $3 + $5, i * 
$4 + $6) AS geom
FROM generate_series(0, $1 - 1) AS i,
 generate_series(0, $2 - 1) AS j,
(
SELECT ('POLYGON((0 0, 0 '||$4||', '||$3||' '||$4||', '||$3||' 0,0 
0))')::geometry AS cell
) AS foo
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;

drop table if exists test_fishnet;
create temp table test_fishnet as select 
st_rotate((ST_CreateFishnet(nrows::integer, ncols::integer, 100, 100, 
st_x(point_tr), st_y(point_tr))).geom, angle_tr, point_tr) as poly from 
test_angle;
```

the test_angle table is basically getting the angle that the oreinted envelope is set at so that I can turn the fishnet to the proper angle

Comment: Does your grid have row & column indexes?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not.

Comment: @geozelot I added an edit to show how I make the grid if that helps.

Comment: Oh I see, just run `SELECT grid."row", grid.col, ST_Rotate(grid.geom, ...) AS poly FROM test_angle, LATERAL ST_CreateFishnet(...) AS grid;` to expand the `RECORD`s and retrieve the indexes. Then get all those whose indexes are between those that intersect the polygons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using simple grid math:

```
WITH
  grid AS (
    SELECT
      grid."row",
      grid."col",
      ST_SetSRID(ST_Rotate(grid.geom, angle_tr, point_tr), <SRID>) AS geom
    FROM
      test_angle
      CROSS JOIN LATERAL
      ST_CreateFishnet(nrows::integer, ncols::integer, 100, 100, ST_X(point_tr), ST_Y(point_tr)) AS grid
  ),
  its AS (
    SELECT
      grid."col", MIN(grid."row") AS minr, MAX(grid."row") AS maxr
    FROM
      grid
      JOIN
      polys
        ON ST_Intersects(grid.geom, polys.geom)
    GROUP BY
      grid."col"
  )
SELECT
  grid.*
FROM
  its
  JOIN
  grid
    ON grid."col" = its."col"
WHERE
  grid."row"
    BETWEEN its.minr
        AND its.maxr
;
```

The above works on pairs of geometries with a distance along the `row` - so connecting cells are identified by the `col` index. If the grid is rotated differently, or the geometries are aligned in a `col` facing way, you need to switch `col` and `row` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. you join the grid to polys based on intersection and group by row, is this to get the rows that intersect? I'm trying to run this but I get the same grid back as I put in.

Comment: @tbob Since you rotate counter-clockwise (as per `ST_Rotate` docs) you may need to pivot the grid for the correct ranges over rows and cols - I changed that in the query accordingly.

Comment: I use this query for collision detection on massive LiDAR point grids. Dead simple and super efficient, thanks. Do you think this could be enhanced to get applied on a full table of polygons, and in both grid dimensions?

Comment: @t.ry potentially, but not as _dead_ simple; I'd start with getting both the min max cols and rows per geometry, then find pairs between the grid projections of your polygons based on both common cols and rows (distinct per pair), then apply the above on each of these distinct pairs.

Comment: Ok I go this to work, I just had to change the setSRID to 102008, and I switched row and column. Thank you

Comment: @tbob I made the SRID a wildcard. I changed row and col in an earlier edit, after my latest comment to you - did you have to revert those changes or use this current version?

Comment: @geozelot Oh I think I must have been doing something else wrong on your first iteration. for this latest one I really took the time to understand it and after switching rows and cols it worked, so yeah, sorry I reverted the changes to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Create a "visibility polygon" as the convex hull of the two polygons, and keep grid cells which intersect it.

Comment: That would most certainly catch a bunch of cells that are in the "yellow zone" in OPs image - you could try fidlding with the *concave* hull parameter to get a better fitting grid aligned coverage polygon.

Comment: Well, yes.  It's not clear if this question is looking for a general technique, or just for this specific case (in which case simply specifying the cells explicitly will work).

Answer (score 1):

So, there are many ways to solve your question and this geospatial approach is one of them.

The input geodata is an oriented grid and two area objects located on its edges, as shown in your and my image :-).

[image]

Figure 1

Run this script, configuring it on your geodata (I don't have it):

```
WITH
tbla AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom FROM test_fishnet),
atbl AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom FROM poly),
tblb AS (SELECT ST_Union(a.geom) geom FROM tbla a JOIN atbl b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
tblc AS (SELECT ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)) geom FROM tblb),
tbld AS (SELECT line1, line2 FROM (SELECT ST_MakeLine(ST_PointN(geom,1), ST_PointN(geom,2)) line1, 
             ST_MakeLine(ST_PointN(geom,4), ST_PointN(geom,3)) line2 FROM tblc) foo),
tble AS (SELECT generate_series (0, 3) as steps),
tblf AS (SELECT steps AS stp1, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(line1, steps/(SELECT count(steps)::float-1 FROM tble)) geom1 FROM tbld, tble GROUP BY tble.steps, geom1),
tblg AS (SELECT steps AS stp2, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(line2, steps/(SELECT count(steps)::float-1 FROM tble)) geom2 FROM tbld, tble GROUP BY tble.steps, geom2),
tblh AS (SELECT stp1, stp2, ST_MakeLine(geom1, geom2) geom FROM tblf JOIN tblg ON true AND stp1=stp2),
tbli AS (SELECT stp1 id, a.geom geom FROM tblh a JOIN atbl b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)), 
tblj AS (SELECT DISTINCT a.id, ST_LineSubstring(ST_OffsetCurve(a.geom, 0.1), 0.1, 0.9) geom FROM tbli a JOIN tbli b ON true) 
 (SELECT ST_Union(a.geom) geom FROM tbla a JOIN tblj b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) GROUP BY a.geom, b.geom UNION
         SELECT ST_Union(a.geom) geom FROM tbla a JOIN atbl b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) GROUP BY a.geom, b.geom)
```

With my test geodata the result is what you are asking for, which is shown in figure 2.

[image]

Figure 2.

The original geospatial solutions...

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I'm going to try to digest this.